# Representing a matrix with unit determinant by the generators of the modular group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, determinant

I know that $a-b+c-1=1$ with $a,b$ and $c$ positive integers. Regrouping the terms we have $a-(b-c+1)=1$. I rewrite that equation as the determinant of a matrix,

$$ e=
  \begin{pmatrix}{}
     a & 1 \\
     b-c+1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Now $e$ is in the group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ which is generated by the matrices

$$ S=
  \begin{pmatrix}{}
     0 & -1 \\
     1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix} ,\space \space
 T = \begin{pmatrix}{}
     1 & 1 \\
     0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

These matrices satisfy the relations $S^{4} = (ST)^{6} = 1$, and $S^{2} = (ST)^{3}$

My question is how do I write $e$ as the multiplication of $S$ and $T$? I keep thinking that since $S$ and $T$ are generators of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ then $e$ can be represented (not necessarily uniquely) with the terms $S$ and $T$? Thanks.

Comment: $c$ is a superfluous parameter... I advise you to consider instead a family of matrices like this one:  $\begin{pmatrix} a +1 & 1\\ab+a+b & b+1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: How and why is the $c$ superfluous?

Comment: This is just elementary linear algebra. You can reduce $e$ to the identity by performing unimodular row and column operations, and these can also be achieved (with a bit of thought) by pre- and post-multiplying $e$ by $S$ and $T$. (Note that $STS^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\-1&1\end{array}\right)$.)

Comment: I am a little slow but thank you. I am going to have to go back and work through this.

Comment: Let me explain my remark: by using three letters, it looks like 3 "degrees of freedom" (in a wide sense) but in fact, your family of matrices depends of  only 1 parameter. Why that ? Because $c$ can be expressed as a function of $a$ and $b$, and, in fact, if you replace $c$ by this expression, the $b$s are cancelled and you are left with the one-parameter family \begin{pmatrix} a  & 1\\ a-1& 1 \end{pmatrix}. So my question is: why use 3 parameters when only one is needed?

Comment: I think I follow you. You are saying for instance write $c$ as $1-a+b+1$ then plug it back into the equation to get the statement $a - (a-1) =1$ which is the determinant of the matrix above in your comment. And how does this change the representation of $e$ with respect to the answer by Holt? Also I was not aware I can reduce the equation to one parameter and still recover any meaningful information after representation by S and T?

Comment: In fact the expression in $S$ and $T$ that I wrote was for the matrix with two parameters $a$ and $b$ in JeanMarie's first comment, and not for the matrix in the question! Sorry about that! I have deleted that comment. But doing it for your matrix is even easier.

Comment: Holt is it the same attack: reduce JeanMarie's matrix to the identity by pre and post compositions with $S$ and $T$.